# How to make complexe query with laravel Query Builder

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

Let consider the senario where i have this table `parameters` with some sample data.
[image]

I need to query these data into three categories as describing bellow.

**query1** = get all records that has: `param1=param2=param3= 100%` as from this case the oupout is the first record. Not problem with this query.

**query2** = get all records that has: `at least param1 < 80 OR param2 < 80 OR param3 < 80 OR all` as from this case the outpout is the second and the third record.

**query3** = get all records that has: `at least param1 >= 80 OR param2 >= 80 OR param3 >= 80 BUT NOT ALL EQUAL to 100%` as from this case the outpout is the fourth and fifth records.

I am really stock at query2 and query3. bellow is my query using laravel query builder.

```
            $query = DB::table('parameters');                
            if ($query === 1) {
                $query->where('param1', '=', 100)
                      ->where('param2', '=', 100)
                      ->where('param3', '=', 100);
            }elseif ($query === 2) {
                $query->where('param1', '<', 80)
                      ->where('param2', '<', 80)
                      ->where('param3', '<', 80);
            }else{
                $query->whereBetween('param1', [80, 100])
                      ->whereBetween('param2', [80, 100])
                      ->whereBetween('param3', [80, 100]);
            }
            $result = $query->get();
```

Hope my question is clair enougth. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be easier for you to use an average of the three params since you have an interval to respect.

```
//param_avg = (param1 + param2 + param3)/3;

$query = DB::table('parameters')->get();
//For query 1
    $query->where('param1', '=', 100)
          ->where('param2', '=', 100)
          ->where('param3', '=', 100); 

//For query2
 $query->where('param1', '<', 100)
       ->where('param2', '<', 100)
       ->where('param3', '<', 100);

//For query3
$query->select(DB::raw('WHERE (param1 + param2 + param3)/3 <=80 AND (param1 + param2 + param3)/3 <100'));
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Happy to know it helped. Happy coding (^_^)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can't use in one query three whereBetween() and in your 
query2 = is you have mention param1,param2,param3 < 80 the query should be

```
$query = DB::table('parameters')
                ->whereBetween('param1', [0, 80])->get();
```

same way query 3

```
$query = DB::table('parameters')
                    ->whereBetween('param1', [80, 100])->get();
```

use query for every column use rules for that all queries
use this link - [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses)

**EDITED ANSWER**

```
public function getData($id)
    {
        $query = DB::table('parameters')->find($id);

        if($query->param1==100 && $query->param2==100 && $query->param3==100){

        }elseif($query->param1<80 or $query->param2<80 or $query->param3<80){

        }else{

        }

    }
```

Route this function properly you will get output :)

Comment: thanks for your  response. But how will i filter for the three parameters if a query can't take three whereBetween() ?

Comment: i have edit my answer im not clear about what you need output just check my answer it will help you sure